# Convert audio to higher speed with VLC

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player

Can VLC do this? There are quite some tutorials on the web but for me, it does not work - new file gets saved, but in original speed.

One tutorial is here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-save-a-video-with-a-changed-playback-speed-in-VLC

So one needs to go to Media > convert > Show more options and then add `:rate=2.0` to double the speed. When i try that on a ogg file, it just saves it at original speed.

Comment: I'd choose an actual audio editor like Ocenaudio or Audacity for this kind of sound manipulation.

Comment: This question might fit better in the VLC forums.

Comment: Why not use ffmpeg? I recall you asking a different question for it.

Comment: Somebody asked me how I sped a video (using ffmpeg). I wanted them to have some easy GUI way to do that and VLC seems to be able to do this but for some reason it does not work.

Comment: So, based on this: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=158378&p=521592&hilit=convert+speed#p521592

the approach I suggested would only change speed of video. However, when I tried it there is a slight de-sync so it is not useful to recommend to others.